# I keep getting erorr Enoent .I have tried All the solutions Still getting the erorr

Tags: reactjs

I am absolute beginner learning ReactJS for the First time.I keep getting following eror
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ARYAN\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ARYAN\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ARYAN\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-25T04_52_16_047Z-debug-0.log

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Node.JS but still getting this erorr for past 1 hour

Comment: The first step is to create the app: `npx create-react-app myapp` this command is not working?

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of your terminal with your command written before you press enter?

Comment: yeah sure but how can I share the screenshot with you ?

Comment: You can host in `imgur` ( can Google It) and share the link here

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yMdwjpE here is the link

Comment: What is your node/npm/npx version? `node -v` `npx -v` `npm -v`

Comment: Maybe this video can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6SXo4IezNs

Comment: node v18.16.1 npm v9.5.1  npx v9.5.1